# Forcing NAs to be shown in regression output from xtable

Tags: r, xtable

`xtable` defaults to removing `NA` values from regression output. I would like to force those coefficients to show up in the output, with their `NA` values. There is an argument `NA.string` to `print.xtable` that I would have thought would provide this functionality, but it does not do anything with `lm` objects at least.

For example,

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=2:4, C=2:4)
reg <- lm(A ~ B + C, df)
print(xtable(reg), NA.string = "Foo")
```

creates the following output

```
% latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Wed Feb  5 11:04:09 2014
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
   \hline
 & Estimate & Std. Error & t value & Pr($>$$|$t$|$) \\ 
  \hline
(Intercept) & -1.0000 & 0.0000 & -Inf & 0.0000 \\ 
   B & 1.0000 & 0.0000 &  Inf & 0.0000 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

while what I would like to have output is

```
% latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Wed Feb  5 11:04:09 2014
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
   \hline
 & Estimate & Std. Error & t value & Pr($>$$|$t$|$) \\ 
  \hline
(Intercept) & -1.0000 & 0.0000 & -Inf & 0.0000 \\ 
   B & 1.0000 & 0.0000 &  Inf & 0.0000 \\ 
   C & NA & NA & NA & NA \\ %%% This is the new line
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I haven't used `xtable`, so guessing. Maybe take a look at the structure of `xtable(reg)` and see if you can manipulate it to add an element `C` of value "NA" similar to the existing whatever contains "B" .

Comment: If you look at summary(reg)$coefficients you will see that is the printed table and it doesn't include the C row; yet print(summary(reg)) shows the NA row.

Comment: I would rather not edit the `xtable` object directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but I found it because I was having a similar problem.

The xtable documentation suggests "NA.string" as the appropriate argument. So you would add NA.string="NA" to print NAs in the output, since the default is an empty space.

Note that if for some reason you can't get it to work but you only have a small number of NAs, you can actually edit the output manually (by inserting NA between adjacent ampersands in each row) in a pinch.

Comment: The crucial observation is that `NA.string` needs to be passed to `print.xtable` not to `xtable` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The example above does not reproduce for me because I think the regression is singular and it does not produce an estimate for the variable named `C` so there is not a row for that in the output. Here is a simplified example with an answer. Note that the `NA.string` argument needs to be passed to the `print()` argument, not the `xtable()` function.

```r
df <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=2:4, C=c(2,3,NA))
print(xtable::xtable(df), 
      include.rownames = FALSE, 
      NA.string = "Foo") 
#> % latex table generated in R 4.3.2 by xtable 1.8-4 package
#> % Thu Feb  1 13:55:07 2024
#> \begin{table}[ht]
#> \centering
#> \begin{tabular}{rrr}
#>   \hline
#> A & B & C \\ 
#>   \hline
#>   1 &   2 & 2.00 \\ 
#>     2 &   3 & 3.00 \\ 
#>     3 &   4 & Foo \\ 
#>    \hline
#> \end{tabular}
#> \end{table}
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping there was an argument I was missing or not using correctly. Perhaps what I am looking for is not possible. I guess I will just manually create a data frame of all of my `NA` coefficients and `xtable` that separately.